# Hooking Up Unit Tests to Local IIS Web Instance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, unit-testing

I'm trying to run unit tests for a project which is reliant on the web instance as it uses integrated windows authentication to verify the current user. When I run the tests it doesn't fire up the web instance, which is expected, but I need it to in order for any tests to succeed really.  Anyone have any idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got this working in the end.  You have to mock `HttpContextBase` (which is preferential over `HttpContext` I hear) and then set up your `IPrincipal` which is returned from the mock object.  I'll give the full code listing so you get the idea:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void SetUp()
{
    userRepositoryMock = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
    controller = new AccountController(userRepositoryMock.Object);

    httpContextMock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    IPrincipal fakeUser = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("johnsmith@johns4232mith.com", "Forms"), null);
    httpContextMock.Setup(x => x.User).Returns(fakeUser);

    var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
    var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
    var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
    var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
    var identity = new Mock<IIdentity>();

    request.Setup(req => req.ApplicationPath).Returns("~/");
    request.Setup(req => req.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath).Returns("~/");
    request.Setup(req => req.PathInfo).Returns(string.Empty);
    response.Setup(res => res.ApplyAppPathModifier(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns((string virtualPath) => virtualPath);
    identity.SetupGet(ident => ident.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);
    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Request).Returns(request.Object);
    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Response).Returns(response.Object);
    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Session).Returns(session.Object);
    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Server).Returns(server.Object);
    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.User).Returns(fakeUser);

    controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(context.Object, new RouteData(), controller);
}
```